# Making sure you dont overwrite a file in .Net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have made a view that takes a file upload and my controller has a http post method that basically saves the path in the db and then saves the file within the app_data dir. However, I want to make sure the file doesnt over write another file. I.e. if another files exists, rename it. I know I could do this in 2 ways, either by ensuring all file names are unique with guid or by renaming the file. I have tried the second approach, but my methodology seems cumbersome. I would appreciate it if anyone can advise on if there is another approach:

here is what I have:

```
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName); //Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/slides"), fileName);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                for (int i = 1; true; i++)
                {
                    path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/slides"), (fileName + "_" + i));
                    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            file.SaveAs(path);

            model.Image = path;   
        }
```

Comment: instead of the i index, or any other loop variable. why don't you use filename + "_" + Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhss") ?

Comment: Personally I'd use the GUID approach, but it still requires you to check for uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/slides"), fileName);

    for (int i = 1; System.IO.File.Exists(path); i++)
        path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/slides"), fileName + "_" + i.ToString() + extension);

    file.SaveAs(path);

    model.Image = path;
}
```

Happy to Help you!

Comment: I'd prefer using Guid instead, but this is your answer.

Comment: I think you should mention race condition and that it's possible for two threads to get the same file name, which does not yet exist, then one creates the file, and another one fails with a critical error.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't check **if exists**, it does not help you in any way, because a file may get added before your following lines execute. You want to have a `Try...Catch` block instead. And you need to actually create a file, not just return a path, which did not exist at some point of execution.

Second, separate your logic of creating a file from your MVC, so code like `Server.MapPath` and `model.Image = path;` would be somewhere else.

Third, timestamp sounds like the best option here, just make sure you include milliseconds. If not enough you can include partial checksum at the end, whichever approach makes it unique. You still need to have code in place that checks uniqueness, even if it would rarely happen, and just regenerate file name again, maybe wait 50ms, to make sure it will be a different file name.

Comment: Guid generates unique names but with this ask, sounds like need to preserve file name.

Comment: @IgorQuirino: guid is a maintenance nightmare, if one decides to manually find a file, and if you have 100K of them in the folder.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Not if you have someone supporting your application on-call. "Please find file ay5h7d5Y, did you say upper or lower case Y?" :)

Comment: ? "myFile.jpg.123456789ABCDD" should be trivially to find... Also obviously if you upload file with non recognizable name...

Comment: You can save the metadata on database. Makes sense?
And then save the physical path as guid on the database.
You can save de database key as filename...
Has many ways to do this...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: You cannot rely on recognizable names. You can rely on timestamp. Ask user at what time they uploaded their stuff. Chance is you get 10-20 files to sweep through, even on a high load system.

Comment: @IgorQuirino: Possible, just more complicated. Now you also need to deal with transactional issues, i.e. deadlocks etc.

Comment: Looks like OP stores meta-info to DB - there is no need to search for file name... Files already have time-stamp - GUID makes uniqueness much easier to achieve... you can also include timestamp if really need it to be part of the name.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Then you can append value of primary key, much more simple in my opinion.

Comment: Sure. Huge assumption so if OP can actually get one from INSERT or setup SQL to produce reasonable PK.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: If OP already has metadata record in DB, they already have a primary key. If they don't already have it, use timestamp approach, it can be a combination of timestamp + thread id or something like that, if too many files are coming at the same time. I still prefer meaningful file names over guids. Also not involving DB in file saving process is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

hopefully this works for you:

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var fullFileName = fileName + "_" + Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhss")
    path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/slides"), fullFileName );
    file.SaveAs(path);
    model.Image = path;   
}
```